# How to set edges to zero?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I'm using Auto-Layout to set the subviews' leading equal to the superviews' leading and so dose the top and the right. But, for example, the origin of the white block in following image still equal to 16.
I'm not familiar with edges, how to make origin start at the 0?
Thank you for any suggestion.
[image]

Comment: remove the checkmark for margins, you are setting your contraints to margins, if your remove the checkmark then you will get your needed results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the checkmark for margins before add a Constraint, you are setting your Constraints to margins, if you remove the checkmark then you will get your needed results

[image]

## UPDATED

**To fix an existing constraint**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. but how to modify it on exiting constrain.

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, my problem solved by unchecking the first item's relative to margin. Thank you again. It confused me a lot.